# Problems running 2 sample NDK applications

Tags: java-native-interface, android-ndk-r4

I have installed the android tool chain within eclipse and am working through all the sample apps under the NDK.  The apps all build fine with ndk-build and were imported into eclipse without issue.  Most of them run just fine on the emulator but 2 have problems:

On the emulator:
hello-neon displays: Not an ARMv7 CPU
san-angeles(hello-gl2) pops up a window with a force close button.: The application GL2JNI (process com.android.gl2jni) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

Has anyone seen these issues and can explain what to change to fix it.
is the android-ndk-r4 the most recent NDK to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a text at the end of STABLE-APIS.TXT in the docs folder that explains this problem:

> The Android emulator does not support OpenGL ES 2.0 hardware emulation at this time.
>   Running and testing code that uses this API requires a real device with such capabilities.